# How can I detect when an element dynamically added has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit: added Handlebar template loading

I am trying to detect when a dynamically added element has been loaded (from a handlebars template), but the event never fires.

Here is the code:

```
var source = $('#mapTemplate').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$('#wrapper').fadeOut(function() {
    $('#wrapper').html(template());
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn();
});
$('body').on('ready', '#mapCanvas', function() {
        alert('Ready')
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"),mapOptions);
    })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This code doesn't show how you are adding the dynamic content. That would be key in helping with this problem

Comment: If you really want to detect when an element is dynamically added, you would  use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver But that would be only a last resort. Usually libs that add elements asynchronously have a callback to notify you.

Comment: In that case, the DOM is available immediately after `$('#wrapper').html(template());`

Comment: @JuanMendes Huh, I wander why i get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null` when loadin the google maps then

Comment: Did you debug if `template()` is returning what you expect? If that string contains the node you expect, it will be there

Comment: @JuanMendes Yeah, the div is loading so I don't know. Oh well, I'll try tommorow - its 13 past midnight here ;)

Comment: jQuery makes the div invisible when fading it in. You have to wait until it's faded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is available on the page immediately after the call to insert handlebar's template

```
$('#wrapper').html(template());
//#mapCanvas should be available
```

However, you're probably getting an error because you are telling the div to fade in and jQuery makes it invisible initially. Be sure to wait until the `fadeIn` finishes.

```
var source = $('#mapTemplate').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$('#wrapper').fadeOut(function() {
    $('#wrapper').html(template());
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn(function() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"),mapOptions);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, there is no `"ready"` event when a template is loaded.

The usual solution to knowing when anything that is dynamically loaded is ready is to supply a completion callback function to the code that is doing the loading.  When that callback is called, the content is available in the page.  I don't know exactly how you're loading the handlebars template, but the handlebars functions I see for loading a template, all take a callback argument that is called after the template has been successfully loaded.  You would then trigger your `map` logic from within that callback.

If you show us the code you're using for loading the template, we can be much more specific.

---

Now, that you've shown us the code, your template is already preloaded and you can restructure you code like this to add the mapping stuff as soon as the fadeIn has finished:

```
var source = $('#mapTemplate').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$('#wrapper').fadeOut(function() {
    $('#wrapper').html(template()).fadeIn(function() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"),mapOptions);        
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why the OP thinks there is a ready event on the body element.

Comment: @JuanMendes Since the element is dynamically loaded, I can't put the event listner on the element itself. I thought if I put it in the body the event would 'bubble up'. Obviously I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: @user2521439 - there is no `ready` event at all.  It's not that it doesn't bubble.  There just isn't such an event.  In some cases there is a `readystatechange` event on the document or involved with an ajax call, but that event isn't on an element within the page.